# Google OAuth 2.0 get Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch, ASP.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am try to connect google drive api with my asp.net core 3.1 web server which run on **http://127.0.0.1:4000** .But during authorizing I get different redirect_uri. And the **credential.json** is all valid.

**The error I get:**

[image]

**My code:**

```
public class GDriveService : BaseService
    {
        private string credentialFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CredentialFile"].ToString();
        private string appName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppName"].ToString();
        private string[] scopes;
        private UserCredential credential;
        private DriveService service;
        public GDriveService(IWebHostEnvironment env):base(env)
        {
            scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                               DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,};


            using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, credentialFileName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                String FilePath = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "DriveServiceCredentials");
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(FilePath, true)).Result;
            }
}
```

**My credential configuration:**

[image]

Comment: Have you submitted your OAuth2 screen configuration for verification?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. @ziganotschka my app in google console is still in Testing phase and I've already submitted OAuth2 consent screen. Still, it does not seems to work. Help?

Comment: I'm using `http://localhost/authorize/` as the redirect URL in GCP, runs the web application from Visual Studio. Then I tried to connect to Google Drive API and failed a few times. Then I refresh my web application (with debugger still attached) and wait for few minutes before I tried again. To my surprise, it works, but only for a while. Weird..

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `http://127.0.0.1/` and `http://127.0.0.1/authorize/` to the Authorized redirect URIs section.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect uri you are sending from must exactly match the one that you have registered.  In your case you are sending from.  (Note this is controlled by the client library)

[image]

You have only registered the following in Google cloud console

[image]

The solution is to add the redirect uri that the error message is telling you exactly including the ending /.

This video will show you exactly how to fix it. [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

Remember to ensure that Visual studio is using a static port.  If your port keeps changing your redirect uri must change as well.